# How to use Request Management Service to route all traffic from a specific host to one WFE?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, troubleshooting, request-management, wfe

We have RM deployed in our farm, and it is causing troubleshooting issues. Is there a way to make RM route all the traffic from a specific IP to a specific WFE?

Even with HOSTS file set to point to a single WFE, RM will still route requests out to the other boxes.

Comment: How big is the farm? Is there a specific reason you need to use RM?

Comment: We have 7 web servers and 3 app/custom servers. Our farm sits behind a F5 traffic manager. If you know of a way to get traffic to go to a specific WFE without using RM I would love to hear.

Comment: Why not just drop RM and use a hosts file on the machine that needs to send requests to a specific FE, bypassing F5?

Comment: We need to do it for long stretches of time and infrequently, so we dont want to keep turning RM off and on on the server.

Comment: Right, you wouldn't need RM at all if the source machine used a hosts file to target a particular FE.

Comment: I'm not sure we are on the same page. The source machine has a HOSTS file set to point at the FE. The problem is that just gets rerouted to another FE in the farm because of RM. I want RM to NOT reroute that traffic and to keep it on that FE.

Comment: Disable RM. Sounds like that would resolve your issue.

Comment: So are you saying there is no way to use RM to just route all the traffic to that FE? Doesn't turning off RM also prevent other servers from using that server for routing as well?